# Overlapping forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem with overlapping forms in Symfony 2. I'm trying to create an application with photos albums.
To do so, I need to create an album and adding him photos during this process. 
Photos are link with onl one album.

I think that my code is right on backend but the photo's form never shown inside the album's form. I think the problem is in the form himself.

A photo have to attribute: a file and a name.

This is my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#thelink_albumbundle_albumtype_photos');

    function add_photo() {
        index = $container.children().length;

        $container.append(
                $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/\$\$picture\$\$/g, index))
        );
    }

    if($container.children().length == 0)
        add_tag();


    $('#add_photo').click(function() {
        add_photo();
    });
});
```

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ form_widget(form) }}


<div id="thelink_albumbundle_albumtype_photos" data-prototype="&lt;div&gt;
    &lt;label class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;$$photo$$&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;div id=&quot;thelink_albumbundle_albumtype_photos$$photo$$&quot;&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;thelink_albumbundle_albumtype_photos$$photo$$_photo&quot;
    class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;Photo&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;input type=&quot;file&quot; id=&quot;thelink_albumbundle_albumtype_photos$$photo$$_photo&quot;
    name=&quot;thelink_albumbundle_albumtype[photos][$$photo$$][picture]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot;
    maxlength=&quot;255&quot; value=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;">
</div>

<br />

<a href="{{ path('TheLinkAlbumBundle_index') }}" title="Retourner sur la liste des Albums">
    Annuler la {% if news is defined %}Modification{% else %}Création{% endif %}
</a>

<input type="submit" value="{% if album is defined %}Modifier{% else %}Créer{% endif %} l'Album" />
```

Do you have any idea ? Or the problem is else where ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're manually entering the data prototype? Assuming "photos" is a collection type. Make sure you have the "allow_add", "allow_delete", and "prototype" options set to true:

```
    ->add('photos', 'collection', array(
        'type'              => new PhotoType(),
        'allow_add'         => true,
        'allow_delete'      => true,
        'prototype'         => true
    ))
```

Then you can just do {{ form_row(form.photos) }} and it should render the prototype automatically.

It would help more if you could post your form type as well.